# How to Handle SharePoint Multi-Value Lookup When There's No Value Separator Present?

Tags: sharepoint

We are sourcing "Order Data" from sharepoint site into Azure Synapse database through "Data Virtuality". Data Virtuality has the connection details for the source Data Sharepoint site.

When I fetched the data from sharepoint, I am getting the multivalues field data without any value separator. Anyone faced this problem earlier and what's the best way to resolve this issue.

Let me explain the context with dummy data:

## Order data shown in the sharepoint site looks similar to the below:

Order ID  Order Date  Branch Name    Products                 Value(£)
BR1      01/10/2022  London         Tea;Coffee               15,000
BR2      31/01/2023  Leeds          Cocoa;Forestry Product;  21,000
Tea

Properties of the "Products" field
1 - It refers the values from "product-reference-table" which has all product data such as productid, product name, label,etc
2 - Allows multiple values; lookup
3 - Allow to show "product name" of the reference table

Product Master data
productid productname label
1          Tea
2          Coffe
..
30         Forestry Product

When I source the ORDER DATA from sharepoint, I am getting the values like the below.
Order, Orderdate, branch, products, value
BR1, 01/10/2022, London, 12, 15000
BR2, 31/01/2023, Leeds, 9301, 21000

Note that there's no value separator in products field.

I tried to look for any separate "listid" values that has a relationship of the order & product combination. But there's no such data in the system. Also tried to find any hidden character in the "product" value field but none.